# Python list() function on (non) iterable

Tags: python-3.x, list

I'm facing an issue with the `list()` function. I have a simple class

```
class Foo(object):
   def __init__(self, value):
      self.value = value
```

And I'm trying to construct a list with the `Foo` object:

```
lhs = list(Foo(1))
...
rhs = list(Foo(2))

return lhs + rhs
```

The desired result should be `[Foo(1), Foo(2)]`. However I need to use such result in the recursive call, so in the following step this result becomes the argument of the `list()` function of `lhs` and I want to append such list by another `Foo` element:

```
lhs = list([Foo(1), Foo(2)])
...
rhs = list(Foo(3))

return lhs + rhs
```

And the final result should be `[Foo(1), Foo(2), Foo(3)]`. The issue is that the `list(Foo(1))` function raises the `TypeError` because the `Foo` is not iterable. Is there any way how to fix it?

**EDIT**

A better use case:

```
def create_foo(value):
   return Foo(value)

def concatenate(lhs, rhs):
   return list(lhs) + list(rhs)


concatenate(concatenate(create_foo(1), create_foo(2)), create_foo(3))
```

Comment: `list((Foo(1),))`? Or just `[Foo(1)]`?

Comment: It sounds like you just need an explicit base case for when you have a single item on the left hand side (or no items returning an empty list, depending what you're doing).

Comment: @jonrsharpe I added a better example. The `[Foo(1)]` would create nested lists which are not the desired result

Comment: Why are you trying to pass both `Foo` instances and sequences of `Foo` instances to `concatenate`? That seems like a bad idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just check for lists and use `.extend` to concatenate, or `.append` to add non-list items:

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value
    def __repr__(self):
        return f'Foo({self.value})'

def concat(*args):
    result = []
    for arg in args:
        if isinstance(arg,list):
            result.extend(arg)
        else:
            result.append(arg)
    return result

a = concat(Foo(1),Foo(2),Foo(3))
print(a)
b = concat(Foo(6),Foo(7))
print(b)
c = concat(a,Foo(4),Foo(5),b)
print(c)
```

Output:

```
[Foo(1), Foo(2), Foo(3)]
[Foo(6), Foo(7)]
[Foo(1), Foo(2), Foo(3), Foo(4), Foo(5), Foo(6), Foo(7)]
```

Comment: Brilliant solution! Thanks a lot